# Let X be a topological space and let A be a subset of X

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Which of the
following statements are true?

a. If $A$ is dense in $X$, then $A^o$ (the interior of A), is also dense in $X$.

b. If $A$ is dense in $X$, then $X\setminus A$ is nowhere dense.

c. If $A$ is nowhere dense, then $X\setminus A$ is dense.

Attempt
a.False Try out $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$

b,Flase Try out $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$

c.I Think its gonna be true because if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{N}$ but hiw can I prove

P.S. I am new and poor in Latex. So forgive any mistakes commited.

Comment: So what is the interior of $\mathbb{R}$ according to the definition? So while your answer is correct you have to come up with a correct counterexample. Your answer to (b) looks right. To prove (c) try writing down all the necessary definitions first and then try to figure out an approach to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. It is false, but not because of your example. Take $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\mathbb Q$.

b. It is false. Again, take $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\mathbb Q$.

c. It is true, but an example doesn't prove it. Suppose that $X\setminus A$ is not dense. Let $B=X\setminus\overline{X\setminus A}$. Then $B$ is a non-empty open set and $B\subset A$. Therefore, $B\subset\mathring{\overline A}$, which is impossible, since $\mathring{\overline A}=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Jose's answer is correct and 100% complete. I just want to say that for (c), you can also  use the fact that $$\overline{A^{c}}=(int(A))^c$$ Having that in mind we can easily conclude that if $A$ is nowhere dense , meaning $int(\overline{A})=\emptyset$ then :

$$\overline{A^c}=(int(A))^c\supset(int(\overline{A}))^c=(\emptyset)^c=X$$